# MySQL table 1 filed DATETIME formatted

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have this table (events) just 1 filed (date):

```
date
2013-11-03 15:11:05
2013-11-04 15:11:05
2013-11-05 15:11:05
```

Now I'm trying this query exactly like this;

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events VALUES (2013-06-27 12:00:00)");
```

any reason why is not updating the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the date and missed the `values` keyword

```
INSERT INTO events values ('2013-06-27 12:00:00')
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8866b/1)

Comment: If you don't want to quote, another option is formatting the date as: 20130627120000 (all together).